# How to check if the number of lines in the file equal the number of characters in each of the lines?

Tags: python

The file must contain between 3 and 10 lines of text. That is, 3 is the minimum acceptable number of lines, and 10 is the maximum number of lines.

All lines must contain exactly the same number of characters.

Each line must contain between 3 and 10 characters. That is, 3 is the minimum acceptable number of characters, and 10 is the maximum. The number of characters per line does NOT have to equal the number of lines in the file.

The only acceptable characters are 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', and '_'.

```
correct_string = False
while correct_string is False:

    string = input("Enter a string? ")
    if len(string) != len(string):
        print("Error: string must have the same number of characters.")
    else:
        incorrect_char = False
        for i in string:
            if i != "X" and i != "x" and i != 'Y' and i != 'y' and i != "_":
                incorrect_char = True
        if incorrect_char is False:
            correct_string = True
        else:
            print("Invalid Character. Contains characters other than 'X', 'x', 'Y' 'y',and '_'")
```

Comment: Read the lines from the file and check their length?

Comment: there is alot wrong with this code ... i dont think the initial if will ever be true ...

Comment: The title of your question mentions a file, but in your code you're reading from stdin. Also, the first conditional is nonsensical: when would the length of a string object not equal the its own length?

Comment: Did you ask this twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048248/how-to-check-if-file-contains-between-3-and-10-lines-of-text

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("my_file.txt") as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
     assert all(len(line) == len(lines[0]) for line in lines[1:]) 
     assert len(lines) == len(lines[0])
```

maybe ... not sure quite what your asking

Comment: Just change line 4 to `assert len(lines) in range(3, 11)`.

Comment: I guess you would also need to add `assert len(lines[0]) in range(3, 11)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_file(f):
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i > 10: return False
        for j, c in enumerate(line.rstrip('\n')):
            if j > 10: return False
            if c not in 'xXyY_':
                return False
        if j < 3: return False
    if i < 3: return False

    return True
```